# Absolute position at bottom of relative with vw dimensions not working

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is the code:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); display: inline-block; width: 70vw; height: 30vw; background: url('ausschnitt.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: 100%;">

    <input type="text" name="ort" placeholder="Ort" style="position absolute; margin-left: 30px; bottom: 30px; width: 140px;">

    <select id="regbday_tag" style="left: 200px; bottom: 30px;">
        <option value="" style="display: none;">Umkreis</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

How can I place the inputs at the bottom with 30px margin from it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
position absolute;
```

=>

```
position: absolute;
```